# How to find pop up form's button action on SO odoo v12?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

sorry about noob question. 
My 2 cents knowledge point me out that I normally can find the action for button. but I cannot find action of "Save & Close" button in sales order.
here is my problem:
1. when I create SO, i need to add "Add a product" button to see the "Create Order Lines" pop up form.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw9Gz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bjuI.png)

2. the pop up form is appeared and I would like to know how to find the "Save & Close" action in this pop up form. can experts guide me where and how to find it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm4cE.png)

updated the last found out:

I saw the button action on javascript file called view_dialogs.js located under odoo/addons/web/static/src/js/views

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiS93.png)

the _save js function was called after clicking "Save & Close" button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilt34.png)

Where can I found saveRecord action method according to above picture on odoo?

this.form_view.saveRecord

I used odoo v12 enterprise version.
BR,
Joozer

Answer (score 0):

What i understand is you need to open the sale order line popup view other that the list view. Please try activating the group "Manage product packaging"

Comment: Omal thank for answer. I just want to find the action of "Save & Close" button on Sales Order Line pop up form. dont understand activating the group "Manage Product Packaging"

Comment: if you want to get the popup form view of sale order line when you click on the add product line, you need to activate that group.

Comment: hi OmaL, i just updated my question and I need to found out this.form_view.saveRecord on javascript file and no idea where can i find it?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Action of "Save & Close" of `sale.order.line` is `create` method of `sale.order.line`.

More detail: odoo have two types of buttons. Let call those: custom buttons and default buttons. In debug mode, when you hover on custom buttons, you will see action. For e.g. action of "Confirm Sale" button is `action_confirm`. Default buttons are buttons for mostly CRUD operations. For e.g. "Save & Close", "Create", "Delete", etc. For those, you won't see action when you hover. Action for those buttons are already predefined. `create` method for "Create", `write` method for "Save", `unlink` method for "Delete", etc.

Comment: hi Pyae, thanks for your response and actually my action is under js file and I would like to know where can I find "this.form_view.saveRecord" js function? i just updated my question.